# PreInvocationAdvice for authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Recently I've been dealing with Sring Security trying to customize it in my own way. For instance, I managed to introduce my authorization logic into a request's execution flow to tell whether the current user is authorized to call some method or not. I've done so by injecting a `PreInvocationAuthorizationAdvice` object where its `before` method is called and I can tell if the process should continue or not.

Now I want to do the same for authentication. I would like to inject my code (somehow, somewhere) where I'll be asked if some specific method needs authentication or not. I know I can do this in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.configure` by calling `antMatchers`, `regexMatchers` etc. But I would rather do this case by case, instead of grouping URLs.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Why would you rather do this on a case-by-case. Typically you use the matching logic to specify which endpoins require authentication and potentially which authorization (role) the user should have. You can also use @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')"), in both cases, the key is to create the correct list of GrantedAuthority when you instantiates the Authentication.

Comment: I understand but I have my own ACL (authentication + authorization) system that I'm trying to fuse with Spring. And in order to do that, I need to find the right place to inject my code. I managed to find the right place for authorization part (`PreInvocationAuthorizationAdvice.before`) and I'm looking for the right place for authentication now.

Comment: ACL is not an easy thing to implement, is it part of the database (does it scope the visibility of data), or is it external ? In CMS systems where data visibility is linked to the user, you can't use declarative security alone, you typically need to find the users permissions, and include some ids in the queries to ensure that you load only what the user can see.

Comment: I totally agree with you that ACL could be hard and challenging. That's why I want to use what I have. If you are interested, here's [my blog](https://challengeenthusiast.wordpress.com/2016/09/04/lets-talk-acl/) explaining the concepts. I've been working on it for a while and now I'm trying to adapt it to Spring.

Comment: Unfortunate the comments are limited, so I will try two write an answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

It almost sounds like you are treating the ACL like an aspect that can be reused on different data sets, and if that's the assumption I'm not sure it holds up.

Last time I built a large system that included permissions, the model was something like this.

- You have a number of users
- You have a number of resources
- You have a number of operations that can be performed on resources.
- You can define roles that define different permission-sets (set of operations)
- You have a number of projects
- The resources are scoped by projects (they have a projectId)
- A user is assigned zero or more roles in each project (mappings)
- A user's access to a resource depends on the user's roles in the project which owns the resource (this could be changed at runtime).

If user U wants to delete resource A, you therefore need to find out what project resource A belongs to, and if the effective permission-set of U (join all roles U may have in the project) contained the "Delete Resource" privileged.

You need to be extremely careful on the backend when writing your SQL/JPA queries, because you can never trust the client. This means that you can't POST the projectId and resourceId, you always have to start with the resourceId, see which project it belongs to and then check if the operation is allowed.

If you have a View All feature, allowing a user to see all resources across projects, and a user can see resources in 3 of 5 projects, you need to ask your security model for a list of projects where the user has the View Resource privileged, and then add those projectIds to the query for loading the data. The projectIds needs to go into the query, just like sorting and pagination parameters. Typically you will need two queries since you also need a count query to calculate the total number of pages.

In my experience, the data model and the ACL are completely intertwined. If you want to make the ACL implementation independent of the data model, I fear you will either end up with an inefficient system that needs to load too much data and then filter away resources based on permissions afterwards. Or you will end up with a system that is overly complicated, because you need a generic way to transfer your ACL logic into the resource loading queries (and in the system I described, they are not simple to begin with).

There may be simpler systems than the one I described where a generic ACL implementation would work, but not on the enterprise stuff I have implemented over the last 8 years.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth description. It is not answering my question but it is some topic that I would like to comment on. The ACL model that I have in mind is a little different. First, you only have one grouping concept (roles) and you use it for grouping resources (you're using it for grouping users too if users can have more than one role). But I prefer two grouping concepts, one for resources and one for users. Then a many-to-many relation will set which role has access to which resource. This way users are related to resources. You can read it all in my post given before.